# Post data using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I made an Android application and I need to Post classA to API:

```
public class ClassA {
    private int itemA;
    private int itemB;
    private List<ClassB> claasB;
}
public class ClassB {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private File image;
}
```

This classB contain image as one of his fields

My questions:

1. what is the correct type of image should be in Java in Android, and correct type at API dot net?
2. what the the correct interface in retrofit to send this data?

3- what should API look like to receive this request

Answer (score 0):

To post file parameters in an api, we have to use the @Multipart annotation with the retrofit post function.
The types of part data that we can receive is  FormItem or FileItem there are some more of them but they are not relevant for using it in android.

**FormItem** : A string which contains data about the FileItem, if we would want to pass file name along with the file.

**FileItem** : It consists of the actual file where each partData would have a name that’s how check distinguish different files.

Creating an ApiIInterface class which contains the @**Multipart** annotation and each of the parameter which represent the part data must be annotated with @Part and it should be of the type of MultipartBody.Part.

[Reference along with api implementation](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/making-multipart-requests-in-android-with-retrofit/)